# Apache jackrabbit: Error while retrieving repository using JNDI

Tags: java, linux, jackrabbit

I am setting up Apache jackrabbit repository on Linux machine and while my server is starting up, I get the following error message

> *ERROR* RepositoryAccessServlet: Error while retrieving repository using JNDI (name=jackrabbit.repository) (RepositoryAccessServlet.java,
>    line 210) along with NameNotFoundException.

Complete stack trace follows

> 14.08.2012 16:35:37 *ERROR* RepositoryAccessServlet: Error while retrieving repository using JNDI (name=jackrabbit.repository) (RepositoryAccessServlet.java, line 210)
>   javax.naming.NameNotFoundException
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.jndi.provider.DummyContext.getBoundObject(DummyContext.java:83)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.jndi.provider.DummyContext.lookup(DummyContext.java:248)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.jndi.provider.DummyContext.lookup(DummyContext.java:255)
>       at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.j2ee.RepositoryAccessServlet.getRepositoryByJNDI(RepositoryAccessServlet.java:206)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.j2ee.RepositoryAccessServlet.getRepository(RepositoryAccessServlet.java:295)
>       at org.apache.jackrabbit.j2ee.RepositoryAccessServlet.getRepository(RepositoryAccessServlet.java:321)
>       at org.apache.jsp.welcome_jsp._jspService(welcome_jsp.java:62)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doForward(PageContextImpl.java:709)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.forward(PageContextImpl.java:680)
>       at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:61)
>       at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   14.08.2012 16:35:37 *INFO * RepositoryAccessServlet:   trying to retrieve repository using rmi. uri=//localhost:1099/jackrabbit.repository (RepositoryAccessServlet.java, line 231)
>   14.08.2012 16:35:37 *INFO * RepositoryAccessServlet: Acquired repository via RMI. (RepositoryAccessServlet.java, line 243)

After searching on google for the Exception which is thrown I could not find any thing relevant.

Can some body point where things are going wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have solved the problem.

Issue was with the permissions on directory structure. Tomcat didn't had enough permissions to access the required directory structure. In my case i was getting the error for repository named jackrabbit.reposiory and i had directory structure like jackrabbit/repository.

Once I made sure tomcat has sufficient permissions on these directories(in my case write permission was lacking), things started moving in the right direction.